# ASP.NET Core 6 - using memorycache in view component

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, in-memory-cache

I am writing an application using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

I have a controller that instantiates an `IMemoryCache` and stores some values into the cache.

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _cache = memoryCache;
}
```

In some other part of the application I assign a value to the cache.

In the `_Layout.cshtml` I am using a view component

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
```

I need to access the cache from the view component.

I set `IMemoryCache` in the constructor, and the try to get the data.

```
public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private const string ClientInfoCacheKey = "ClientInfo";
    private  IMemoryCache _cache;

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
         _cache = memoryCache;
         var fromCache = _cache.Get<string>(ClientInfoCacheKey);
         // ......
    }
}
```

But the problem I am facing is that `_cache` is always null...

Is there a way to access cache from a view component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject `IMemoryCache` to your `MenuViewComponent` from constructor. Your code should be:

```cs
public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private const string ClientInfoCacheKey = "ClientInfo";
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public MenuViewComponent(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {         
         var fromCache = _cache.Get<string>(ClientInfoCacheKey);
         // ......
    }
}
```